# Loading the databases from previous installation mysql

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6

My Windows OS crashed today. Now I have recovered all the files in Program files/MySQL folder.(I don't have the exported .sql file)

With the new installation of MySQL 5.6(same as before), can I get those databases back(Or how to load the data to new installation of MySQL)? Please suggest.

Comment: do you see your databases/tables when you run SHOW DATABASES/TABLES?

Comment: @akuzminsky No. I don't see any old tables.

Comment: Run SELECT @@datadir and see what's in this directory. Are there any database data files?

Comment: @akuzminsky yes. Oh. yes there are. Should I just replace it there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your question, I will assume you know the old data root in Program Files MySQL. If you simply copy the entire thing into the data root of your new MySQL 5.6, and then restart, you should be good to go. The .myi .myd and .frm files are the key parts as I understand it.

If you are unsure where the new data root is, check your new installation's my.ini file.